# The export dictionary is empty

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, export

I tried to change the value in dictionary. When i use console.log() i found the value already added into the dictionary, However, when i export the value, it's shows the dictionary is empty.

when i console the code in class, it shows values already added into the dictionary and list. however, when i use it outside of the class. the list and dictionary is empty.

```js
//this is the list and dictionary i want to export
var list = [];
var QuantityDict = {};
 
export default class OrdersList extends React.Component {
 render() {
  const {
   items,
  } = this.props;

  for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
   var id = items[i].items[0].id;
   var name = items[i].items[0].name;
   var quantity = items[i].items[0].quantity;

   list.push([id,name,quantity]);
  }
  
  for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
   var name = list[i][1];
   var quantity = list[i][2];

   if(name in QuantityDict){
    QuantityDict[name]+=quantity;
   }else{
    QuantityDict[name]=quantity;
   }
  }
        //the list length is not 0 in this step.
  console.log('list.length in function: '+list.length);
  for(var key in QuantityDict){
   console.log('key: '+key+' ---value: '+QuantityDict[key]);
  }


  return (.....
  );
 }
}


//the list length is 0 at this step.
console.log('list.length in function: '+list.length);

//the QuantityDict is empty when i try to export it
for(var key in QuantityDict){
 console.log('key: '+key+'---value: '+QuantityDict[key]);
}

console.log(QuantityDict.length);

export {QuantityDict}
```

Comment: Why do you need to extend  React.Component?

Comment: Because I want to use this.props get items from parent class

Answer (score 0):

When you import your component into your app/index.js(or elsewhere) its module(scope) variables/functions are hoisted on the top. While only accessible to your React class/function, they are declared/run immediately on import. (They are sort of like private globals)
All these console.logs are immediately run while React.component is run after being attached to the `React.DOM`.

Consider this code

```
  const { eat, bananas} = (()=>{

    let bananas={count:5};

    function eat(){
      bananas.count-=1;
      console.log('inside eat func', bananas)
    }

    console.log('before return', bananas)

    return { eat, bananas };
    })();

  eat();
  console.log('after calling eat', bananas)
```

console.log result

```
before return {count: 5}
inside eat func {count: 4}
after calling eat {count: 4}
```

It could have been a different file

```
  const { eat, getBananas} from '../...'
```

but would work exactly the same.

Same example with React

```
const { OrdersList, QuantityDict} = (()=>{ 
      var QuantityDict = {count:0};

      class OrdersList extends React.Component {
        state = {id:Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)};
        render() {

          QuantityDict['count'] +=1;
          console.log('inside render '+this.state.id,QuantityDict)

          return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
        }
      }
      console.log('before return',QuantityDict)

      return { OrdersList, QuantityDict};
    })();

    const ff = new OrdersList({name:'World'});
    ff.render();

    console.log('after import',QuantityDict)

    ReactDOM.render(
      <OrdersList name="World" />,
      document.getElementById('container')
    );

    console.log('after React.DOM',QuantityDict)
```

logs

```
before return {count: 0}
inside render 55 {count: 1}//id 55 = ff manual  initialization and render call
after import {count: 1} // QuantityDict still got updated
inside render 66 {count: 2}//id 66 React.DOM
after React.DOM {count: 2}
```

Here as you see I additionally initialized OrdersList manually but it's a different instance, naturally. Albeit both instances share the same scope therefore calling render on it affects QuantityDict.count and bumps it up to 1

```
const ff = new OrdersList({name:'World'});
ff.render();
```

Without it logs are

```
before return {count: 0}
after import {count: 0}
inside render 21 {count: 1}
after React.DOM {count: 1}
```

That also is the reason why you should be careful declaring variables(unless it is a const) outside your React.Component. If your component depends on it, mutating that variable will affect all instances of the component.

TL:DR: Your dictionary will be populated with data when component's render function is called. Either called directly by you( could useful for testing), called by React.DOM when your web page/live-server starts or simply when you run your main file, one way or another, where your React.DOM is located.